# Как поместить в QTableWidget изображение?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Необходимо поместить в QTableWidget изображение, с возможностью его перемещать внутри таблицы по ячейкам, как это делается нормально?

Comment: Использовать [QTableWidgetItem::setIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#setIcon), но если иконку нужно на всю ячейку разместить, либо как то более хитро размещать иконку, тогда через [делегаты](https://github.com/gil9red/combustion) нужно отрисовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим способом:
Создал объект класса `QTableWidgetItem` и через `setBackground` установил фон.

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
QBrush brush;
QBrush.setTextureImage(QImage("image file"));
item->setBackground(brush);
```

Далее просто вставил элемент в нужную клетку в таблице:

```
table->setItem(row, column, item);
```